# One of my Custom Dimensions not showing up completely on Google Analytics?

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

I created 3 custom dimensions through Google Tag Manager (added them as Data Layer Variables). Then, I added custom fields to my pages for these 3 custom dimensions.

After waiting about 24 hours, I checked the three custom dimensions on Google Analytics and two of them have showed up for all of the pages. The last one is showing up for maybe 4-5 pages, but not all of them. It's now been more than two days and the other pages still haven't populated with the last custom dimension.

Is there a  quicker way to see if this third custom dimension is showing up for all of the pages with the designated custom field?

Since this is being done on a test site, most pages have not been visited a ton. Not sure if this can also matter for how long it takes Google Analytics to populate the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the chrome extension 'GA debugger' and go yourself to the site. On the console you ll see each hit sent to GA and all the fields that are being populated.

PS: Custom dimensions ll show up as 'cdX' where X is the number of the dimension.

Comment: Thank you! They're all showing up now as well. Must've just taken more than a few days to show the tracking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing the custom dimensions along with pageveiw. you can check the GA tags that are firing in network tab of your browser only to validate

In your browser access inspect element by right cliking on website and select network tab you can check the screenshot mentioned in the below URL to make all setting required to see GA tags in network tab

http://imarunkumar.blogspot.in/2016/08/blog-post.html

And then reload the page and you can see the Google analytics tags firing, check your tags if custom dimensions are being sent in the tags.

I hope you have provided the right custom dimension index number in GTM while creating the tags. Assume you are sending data to custom dimension 1,2,3 the in tag you can see the values sent.

1. cd1:xxxxxx
2. cd2:xxxxxx
3. cd3:xxxxxx

This confirms that Custom dimension tags are being captured on the page and sent through GA tags to Google analytics.

What if you can see these custom dimension beign sent through the tags but you cannot see the same in reports.

Here the custom dimension configuration you did on the analytics property needs to be reviewed.

As you are collecting all the custom dimension at every page the scope for these custom dimensions should be set at "HIT" level.

Let me know if you are facing any issue in checking them according to the instructions provided above.